# Using symbolic links inside OS X application bundles

Tags: macos, bundle

I'm having a following problem. I have a bundle that has the following structure:

```
B.app/Contents/Frameworks -> link to an existing FS location [1]
B.app/Contents/Info.plist
B.app/Contents/MacOS
B.app/Contents/MacOS/AliasBinary -> link to an existing binary called ExistingBinary [2]
B.app/Contents/Resources -> link to an existing FS location [3]
```

Links [1] and [3] are just links to existing filesystem locations (i.e. directories) that are *outside* of the bundle. **AliasBinary** is a link to another application that I don't want to copy to the bundle, but would like to share it between many bundles. The latter binary is called **ExistingBinary**

The problem I'm having is that calling

```
$ open B.app
```

does open the application but only if the previous instance of **ExistingBinary** is not running. The same applies for double clicking on B.app. If there's no previous instance of **ExistingBinary** running then everything works correctly. Once **ExistingBinary** is started I can no longer start B.app by double clicking or by calling `open B.app`

Help!

EDIT:

The funny fact is that everything works if the bundle is inside /Applications but when I move it outside /Applications it just restores focus on the first instance of an app.

open -n helps, but that's not what I want :)

Answer (score 0):

This may be the default launch services behaviour of not opening existing applications twice.

In Leopard, try

```
open -n B.app
```

or if you have the launch utility:

```
launch -m B.app
```